# How to change style of one row in asp.net repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I would like to change style of one row in asp:repeater control after button click which is in selected row cell.

Especially I would like to disable this row and with styles show that it is disabled. I don't want only to disable button and change row visibility. I want to change style.

How to change row style in asp repeater in code behind?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onitemdatabound` event of `asp:repeater` to do this. In `asp:repeater` you have to write:

```
onitemdatabound="Rptr1_ItemDataBound"
```

Where `Rptr1_ItemDataBound` is my method name in the code behind:

```
protected void Rptr1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //Your custom code goes here
}
```

For better help please post your code.

Comment: Thanks, but strictly I am asking for as you said custom code.

Comment: e.Item.FindControl()... like this u can get the control...on which u need to add style... tht control should have id and runat="server" property. if its a html control u cn retrieve to HTMLGenericControl class by casting. and can use Attribute.Add to add your attributes like class or style etc. Thats why i mentioned for the code where u r facing problem.

Comment: @ElConrado You didn't "ask" anything in your question other than "How to do that", learn to be more specific.